# MySQL Duplicate key name

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, duplicates

I cannot for the love of all that is holy figure out why I am getting this error:

```
Error: Duplicate key name 'Row_In'
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1061
```

When I try to create this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Row_In(
Rower_Email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
Boat_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Race_time TIME NOT NULL,
Reg_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Reg_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Rower_Position ENUM('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8', 'C') NOT NULL,
Boat_College VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Boat_Gender ENUM('M','W') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Rower_Email, Boat_Name, Race_Time, Reg_Name, Reg_Date, Rower_Position, Boat_College, Boat_Gender),
FOREIGN KEY Row_In(Rower_Email) REFERENCES User(Primary_Email),
FOREIGN KEY Row_In(Boat_Name, Boat_Gender, Boat_College) REFERENCES BOAT(Name, Team_Gender, Team_College),
FOREIGN KEY Row_In(Race_time,  Reg_name ,Reg_Date) REFERENCES RACE(Race_Time, Reg_Name, Reg_Date)
);
```

I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the final foreign key, referencing RACE. I was able to create another table with an identical foreign key, but I cannot get it to work in this table.

Please help.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY Row_In(Rower_Email)` => `Row_In` is not the name of the table but instead put the name of the foreign key (and it should be unique). eg, `FOREIGN KEY ROW_IN_EMAIL_FK(Rower_Email) REFERENCES User(Primary_Email)`

Comment: are you building your primary key on all columns of this table? (just a question, it's a little unusual)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the same **index_name** `Row_In` for three foreign keys.

Here is the syntax for Foreign Key definition in MySQL:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Try this instead:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Rower_Email) 
        REFERENCES User(Primary_Email),
FOREIGN KEY (Boat_Name, Boat_Gender, Boat_College) 
        REFERENCES BOAT(Name, Team_Gender, Team_College),
FOREIGN KEY (Race_time,  Reg_name ,Reg_Date) 
        REFERENCES RACE(Race_Time, Reg_Name, Reg_Date)
```

Comment: You are a wizard. I will name my first born son after you.

Comment: Well you don't have to do that. But the Green Checkmark will do! ;-)

Comment: @TomKreamer, do you now have Derek W?

Comment: Also interested :D